# Can players use cards from a core set in a Block Constructed tournament?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What are the rules regarding playing DCI sanctioned Block Constructed formats with cards from a core set such as M15? (I'm thinking of Innistrad-Avacyn Restored block).

Do all players in a game have to use the core set? Can they use blocks that are different from one another's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the currently sanctioned Block Constructed formats include any core sets.

All players in a sanctioned Block Constructed tournament must be using the same block.

The list of currently available Block Constructed formats that can be sanctioned is in the Magic Tournament Rules, that you can find here:

http://wpn.wizards.com/en/resources/rules-documents

Comment: @Rainbolt, oh wow.